# how I check my java print method work properly without physical printer

Tags: java, printing

I have print method for html document in my application. I have no access to a physical printer. since I didn't connect the computer to a physical printer I got the "no printer service found" as specified in code. can I check that function work properly when I connect the computer to a printer without physical printer?

```
     FileInputStream psStream = null;  
        try {  
            psStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\some.html");  
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {  
              ffne.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            if (psStream == null) {  
                return;  
            }  
        DocFlavor htmlStreamFlavor = new DocFlavor("text/html; charset=utf-16", "java.io.InputStream");  
        Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, htmlStreamFlavor, null);    
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();  
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(htmlStreamFlavor, aset);  

        // if several printers configured  
        PrintService myPrinter = null;  
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++){ 
            String svcName = services[i].toString(); 
            System.out.println("service found: "+svcName);              
            if (svcName.contains("printer closest to me")){  
                myPrinter = services[i];  
                System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);  
                break;  
            }  
        }  

        if (myPrinter != null) {              
            DocPrintJob job = (DocPrintJob) myPrinter.createPrintJob();  
            try {  
            job.print(myDoc, aset);  

            } catch (Exception pe) {pe.printStackTrace();}  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("no printer services found");  
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are logical printers that create a pdf instead of printing. For your application they look just like a normal printer.

See this rather long list for options: https://www.google.de/search?q=pdf+printer

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual printer, for example: [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) is really easy to install and you can use it from your program as if it was a real printer.